# Stack mutliple diplacements

Tags: displacement

I want to recreate those glass-bricks. For the deformation I thought to use different noise/musgrave texture as displacements.

[image]

The bricks are deformed in different sizes:

1. The whole bricks are deformed/curved - one is standing more out than the other - for that I use a really big noise

   [image]
2. the surface is not completely flat so I want to use a smaller noise to add the little bumps

   [image]
3. and finally there are fine lines for which will use another noise texture

How can I stack one displacement on top of another?
First I want to have the big displacement, then when the brick is deformed the next displacement starts to displace the surface again and so on.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

You can combine multiple color sources using the Mix node :

1. Big noise : [image]
2. Small noise : [image]
3. Mix node  : [image]

The great benefit of the Mix node is that you can adjust the blending of the levels of details. Here I've set the Fac to a very low value, so that the little details are barely visible.

Comment: the problem i have with this method is, that it creates a mixture of the texture and not a chronoligical adition. Areas that are already 100% black or white cant be affected by the same color from the following texture again.. becaus its already at 100%. 
What i want is that blender calculates the first displacement, shape 1, then adds another displacement on shape 1 to get shape 2. 
what blender  does now it takes displacement 1 and 2, creates a median of those two: shape 1.

or am i undestanding blender in this case wrong?